# Is it safe to move a Visual Source Safe project folder to another location?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have a Visual Source Safe project in folder VSS with the structure "data", "temp" and "users" under. Is it safe to just move this VSS folder to another location on the hard drive and open the project from there or will thousands of file links become broken?

Comment: Well... just try ! But my guess is that it shouldn't be a problem at all

Comment: What is the current status of the project? Is it checked out? If so, it's recommended that you check in the current changes, check it out to the new location and then work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done this several times, I can say that it is safe.  However you must copy All the files.   As indicated by @Rachel it is better if some tidy up has been undertaken first.

I have used this approach to backup before attempting something which could be destructive, for example archiving some old projects.